# Windows XP Resolution is stuck on 800x600 Gateway LT27

Tags: windows-xp, netbook, resolution

So I formatted my whole netbook 256GB SSD and installed Windows XP Professional, and plan to dualboot. I first started with Windows XP, and the install went smoothly, I splitstreamed my old Windows XP disc with SP3 for less hassle. The computer is up to date, I installed all the drivers on the Gateway support page, however the resolution wont budge from 800x600. The native resolution of the netbook is 1024x600 on a 10.1" display, and I cant understand the problem. Any help out there? It is a Intel Atom N450, Graphics Media Accelerator 3150, 1GB RAM and 1.67 GHz CPU. In the device management program, there are two things in the display adapters, It says the GMA1350 twice, both have exclamation marks in them.

I am currently installing Ubuntu alongside XP, and even Ubuntu can identify the native display, why can't XP? Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It appears there's some issue with the drivers, and its stuck in the default, failsafe mode. I'd suggest removing the drivers and trying to install the drivers again. I'd also try the 'generic' intel drivers over the gateway ones to see if that works.

Comment: When I try to remove the drivers it says "This driver cannot be uninstalled because it is needed at boot." And I hit OK and I cant find a way to uninstall.

Comment: boot into safe mode and try

Answer (score 2):

The driver is clearly the issue and that is why the exclamation mark.  I would look for teh Intel chopset driver bundle.  You may need to go to Intel and lookup the chipset you use.

I would also try re-installing the video driver from the Gateway site

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, delete the display adapters in device manager, and the monitor also for good measure. Then either restart of choose Action/Scan for hardware changes in device manager (I'd go for the restart personally).  It probably won't work but is so simple to try - and it does do the job sometimes! (quite safe also).

Failing that, its down to trawling for different drivers that are a better match than the one you are using, which tends to involve a lot of trial-and-error, if you can't find a relevant Gateway forum.
(I'm assuming that when you say it won't let you uninstall the drivers you are doing something different to my suggestion, as I've never had the computer rebel when I've tried to delete in that fashion.  If I'm wrong, then my suggestion isn't going to be any use!)